# subquery and join not giving the same result

Tags: sql

1

```
select *
from employees
where salary > (select max(salary) from employees where department_id=50)
```

2

```
select *
from employees e left join
     employees d
     on e.DEPARTMENT_ID  =d.DEPARTMENT_ID 
where d.salary > (select max(salary) from employees where department_id=50)
```

why the second query is giving multiple record
i want achieve the same result as of 1st query using join.....
Thanks in Advance......

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) I simply cannot imagine why you would think that the two queries would return similar results.  They are very different.

Answer (score 0):

Rocky, the first select is correct. Why do you want to do any join? Without further information the objective of the second select is not clear (nonsense).

I can't see the point about joining against the same table by DEPARTMENT_ID. Anyway, the problem about duplicates is because you are joining the same two tables by a key is not pk, basically you are multiplyng each employee for all the employees of the same department. This version eliminate duplicates but still has no improvement from the first one.

```
select *
from employees e left join
     employees d
     on e.employee_ID  = d.employee_ID 
where d.salary > (select max(salary) from employees where department_id=50)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for an anti join. This is a pattern mainly used in a young DBMS where `IN` and `EXISTS` clauses are slow compared to joins, because the developers focused on joins only.

You are looking for all employees whose salaries are greater than all salaries in department 50. With other words: **WHERE NOT EXISTS** a salary greater or equal in department 50.

Your query can hence be written as:

```
select *
from employees e
where not exists 
(
  select null
  from employees e50
  where e50.department_id = 50
  and e50.salary >= e.salary
);
```

As an anti join (an outer join where you dismiss all matches):

```
select *
from employees e
left join employees e50 on e50.department_id = 50 and e50.salary >= e.salary
where e50.salary is null;
```